# Serialize HTML5 attributes without values in xslt 3

Tags: xslt-3.0

Is there a way to serialize HTML5 attributes without values in XSLT 3?

My goal is to produce something like:

```
<div ui-focused>...</div>
```

As far as I understand it's valid HTML5 output.

Comment: _Is there a way_?, YES.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is that an attribute defined in the HTML5 spec? Then I think it should be serialized as you want, given the right output method, for instance in http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/6qM2e25 the

```
<select>
    <option>a</option>
    <option selected="selected">b</option>
    <option>c</option>
</select>
```

is serialized as

```
<select>
    <option>a</option>
    <option selected>b</option>
    <option>c</option>
</select>
```

But if the attribute is not known as a boolean one to the XSLT processor I don't think there is a way you can tell it to serialize it as empty. On the other hand I don't think an HTML parser is going to misinterpret a format like `ui-focused="ui-focused"`.

See also https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/infrastructure.html#sec-boolean-attributes.

Comment: The attribute I need is not defined in html 5 spec but used by javascript library (some angular directive). Anyway that is answer to the question.